# Cakephp excel report using XLS helper gives an warning message in windows and displays entire xml structure in open office

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using cakephp XLS helper to generate Excel report in my project.
But the generated file is giving warning message in windows system as below.
[image]

Similarly the same file displays the entire xml mark-up in open-office on linux as below.[image]
Part of the view file code is as below.

```
$xls->setHeader('Report_'.date('Y_m_d'));
$xls->addXmlHeader();
$xls->setWorkSheetName('Enrollment Report');

//1st row for columns name
$xls->openRow();
$xls->writeString('ID');
$xls->writeString('Zipcode');
```

My Client wants a proper excel report with-out any warnings in windows.
Please suggest me any excel helper for cakephp which will generate proper excel file on all the platform and different application.

Comment: Where did you get the helper? AFAIK it's not part of the standard package.

Comment: I'm guessing [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/melgior/2010/01/26/simple-excel-spreadsheet-helper), but still not sure - there's a 2007 one as well.

Could you include your full view code? Just that little snippet is not enough to debug with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a helper that puts your data in xml format. Excel can read XML and HTML but with a warning. You should use the one that Ivo suggested in the comments. [LINK](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/melgior/2010/01/26/simple-excel-spreadsheet-helper)
This helper really makes an xls valid format, that complys with open office and office. Also, this helper relies on PHPExcel class that is constantly updated [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) so your code will be easy to upgrade if needed.

Remember to follow instructions given in the helper page.

I've tried a lot of this xls helper for cakephp, but neither one work as expected, either outdated or create xml o html tables or didn't work at all, haven't tried this one though... still creating a helper using PHPExcel shouldn't give you much trouble, you may use [this tutorial](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/05/07/4606.aspx) as a how to base to modify the helper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the mime-type. This has happened to me in the past and it was when the mime-type of an older excel helper was set to an out-dated value.

The code from the linked (by Ivo) helper has the following:

```
function _output($title) {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$title.'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($this->xls);
    $objWriter->setTempDir(TMP);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

I would make sure you are:

a) using the newest helper (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/melgior/2010/01/26/simple-excel-spreadsheet-helper)

b) that the mime-type is actually set.

c) that that specific mime-type is accurate.